# Flutter web show popup menu on hover and remove on mouse exit

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

Is there a way to achieve popup menu on header which expands on hover and closes on mouse exit

Comment: There's a widget called `MouseRegion` with properties `onEnter` and `onExit`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the MouseRegion widget to determine the hover changes. Popup in the sense, could you explain what exactly you want to achieve? Some would be possible some wouldn't be. I hope you just need to expand the menu button on hover, which you can use an AnimatedContainer for the menu, warp it with MouseRegion widget, declare a variable that says the width, and height of AnimatedContainer widget. MouseRegion has onEnter and onExit functions, onEnter is when the container has hovered and onExit is when the user stops hovering the container. During onEnter you can increase the width and height and during onExit, you can set it to default.

```
double _animatedContainerHeight = 30; //Default height
double _animatedContainerWidth = 30;  //Default width
MouseRegion(
   onEnter: (value) {
       setState(() {
          _animatedContainerHeight = 50; //OnHover height
          _animatedContainerWidth = 50; //OnHover width
        });
     },
     onExit: (value) { setState(() {
          _animatedContainerHeight = 30; //Return back to normal height
           _animatedContainerWidth = 30; //Return back to normal width
       });
     },
  cursor: SystemMouseCursors.click, //Cursor type on hover
  child: AnimatedContainer(
  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
  height: _animatedContainerHeight, //Animation height control
  width: _animatedContainerWidth, //Animation width control
   ),
)
```